# What is the possible value of `SizeOfInfo` of the `EFI_GRAPHICS_OUTPUT_PROTOCOL.QueryMode()`?

Tags: uefi

According to [the UEFI specification](https://uefi.org/specifications), the caller of the `EFI_GRAPHICS_OUTPUT_PROTOCOL.QueryMode()` must not assume the size of `Info`. What is the possible value of `SizeOfInfo` then, except `sizeof(EFI_GRAPHICS_OUTPUT_MODE_INFORMATION)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EFI_GRAPHICS_OUTPUT_MODE_INFORMATION can be extended in future versions of the specification in a fully backward compatible way by adding fields at the end. Software that is aware of the additional fields can detect their presence by looking at the size. Software that is not aware of the additional fields would ignore them.

Since no such extensions are currently defined, probably SizeOfInfo is equal to sizeof(EFI_GRAPHICS_OUTPUT_MODE_INFORMATION) in all current implementations.